# DNSMasq server returns no answer section when queried with dig

Tags: dnsmasq

I am trying to get dnsmasq working in CentOS 7 using the tutorial
https://linuxhint.com/configure_dnsmasq_centos/

**here are the relevant config files**

/etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
port=5353
domain-needed
bogus-priv
strict-order
domain=mallet.lan
expand-hosts
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
Generated by NetworkManager
search home
nameserver 192.168.1.100
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost   localhost.localdomain   localhost4  localhost4.localdomain4
::1             localhost   localhost.localdomain   localhost6  localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.1.100   ns.mallet.lan
192.168.1.50    www.mallet.lan
```

**here are outputs of relevant commands**

*dnsmasq is active and running*

```
$ systemctl status dnsmasq
● dnsmasq.service - DNS caching server.
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-10-28 17:01:45 AEDT; 1min 46s ago
 Main PID: 28656 (dnsmasq)
    Tasks: 1
   CGroup: /system.slice/dnsmasq.service
           └─28656 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -k

Oct 28 17:01:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started DNS caching server..
Oct 28 17:01:45 localhost.localdomain dnsmasq[28656]: started, version 2.76 cachesize 150
Oct 28 17:01:45 localhost.localdomain dnsmasq[28656]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus no-i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-con...inotify
Oct 28 17:01:45 localhost.localdomain dnsmasq[28656]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Oct 28 17:01:45 localhost.localdomain dnsmasq[28656]: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53
Oct 28 17:01:45 localhost.localdomain dnsmasq[28656]: using nameserver 192.168.0.1#53
Oct 28 17:01:45 localhost.localdomain dnsmasq[28656]: using nameserver 192.168.1.100#53
Oct 28 17:01:45 localhost.localdomain dnsmasq[28656]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#53
Oct 28 17:01:45 localhost.localdomain dnsmasq[28656]: read /etc/hosts - 4 addresses
```

*enp6so is set to the address of ns.mallet.lan*

```
$ ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:68:d1:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute enp6s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::db4:c8af:1a4b:ee6b/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

3: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:e6:ba:c8:f8:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.40/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic enp2s0
       valid_lft 50110sec preferred_lft 50110sec
    inet6 fe80::1683:279d:161c:b014/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:a6:6d:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:a6:6d:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

*ns.mallet.lan returns a ping*

```
$ ping ns.mallet.lan

PING ns.mallet.lan (192.168.1.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ns.mallet.lan (192.168.1.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.089 ms
64 bytes from ns.mallet.lan (192.168.1.100): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
^Z

[6]+  Stopped                 ping ns.mallet.lan
```

*No expected ANSWER SECTION when queried with dig*

```
$ dig ns.mallet.lan

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.15 <<>> ns.mallet.lan
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 27114
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns.mallet.lan.         IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           86390   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2023102701 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 16 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Oct 28 16:51:49 AEDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 117

$ dig 192.168.1.100

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.15 <<>> 192.168.1.100
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 56801
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;192.168.1.100.         IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           86363   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2023102701 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 16 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Oct 28 16:54:46 AEDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 117

*NXDOMAIN returned when queried with nslookup*

$ nslookup ns.mallet.lan
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find ns.mallet.lan: NXDOMAIN

$ nslookup 192.168.1.100
** server can't find 100.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
```

so..
ns.mallet.lan answers a ping but returns NXDOMAIN and no Answer  Section with dig.
nslookup returns NXDOMAIN.

what am I doing wrong here?

I thought perhaps the line
`Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)`
may imply the service needs to be enabled but I checked the tutorial at
https://linuxhint.com/configure_dnsmasq_centos/
and it has the same output.

Comment: I suggest that you take the [tour](https://serverfault.com/tour). SF is *not* a place for covering steps in tutorials. I would suggest either Unix StackExchange or Superuser.com for such questions.

Comment: Please use [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts to improve their readability. When using copy-and-paste for posting console output, code, logs and messages that rely on formatting please format such text as "`code`" rather than posting without formatting. That improves readability and attracts better answers.

Comment: `ping ns.mallet.lan` uses the system resolver and that uses entries in `/etc/hosts` (when those exist) before querying any DNS server. That's why ping succeeds. - In your dig output you see that in the `;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8` section of the response that the query was sent to and answered by Google's public resolver. That's why it fails. - When debugging nameservers you usually force dig to query a specific name server to prevent it from using entries in /etc/resolv.conf i.e. [`dig @server name type`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) - You  only update /etc/resolv.conf once everything works OK.

Comment: And finally, to lookup a reverse DNS record you need a `-x` option , i.e. `dig @SERVER -x 192.168.1.100` OR use `dig PTR 100.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa`.